# How to stop Google from recording my applications usage on Android?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

When I went to see Google's `My Activity`, I noticed it actually recorded several elements from my usage of applications on my phone (Nexus 5X, with Android 7). For instance, it showed me that it knew I opened a game yesterday, as well as several other applications.

I don't remember seeing this when I was using Android 6, though I haven't used `My Activity` extensively so I don't know.

Is it possible to prevent Google from collecting this <del>stalking</del> personal data at all? If yes, how?

Comment: This was present in earlier versions as well (at least i have seen it when running Marshmallow, it may have been added earlier).

Comment: Sorry didn't see the other answer when I posted mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent this data's collection by Google.

Log into your Google account on the web and visit "My Account".

From the section "Personal Info and Privacy" select
"Manage Your Google Activity"/Activity.

Selectively remove permissions from the presented sections:

1. "Web & App Activity",
2. "Location History",
3. "Device Information",
4. "Voice & Audio Activity",
5. "YouTube Search History", or
6. "YouTube Watch History"

Selectively turn off all or some, to taste, though you would probably get a big benefit from the first section.

Comment: Great, this seems to work so far! :) I'll give the check now 'cause I'll probably forget to come back here to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to Nougat but based on Marshmallow , so am *guessing* it should pretty much be same

- New look and scheme was reported in June this year - [Google launches new My Activity site, reaffirms Google knows basically everything about you](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/06/28/google-launches-new-my-activity-site-reaffirms-google-knows-basically-everything-about-you/)
- On *my activity* page select activity controls

[image]

- You can control ( enable / disable) the following:

  - Web & App Activity
  - Location History
  - Device Information
  - Voice & Audio Activity
  - YouTube Search History

Google would know nearly all you did if you don't disable, so *stalking* isn't far off the mark !